# override django_adminreadonlyfield.html

Tags: django-admin, overriding, fieldset

I'm working on the django admin change form page, using django 1.8 and material design. I have a field, color, which was a long array that didn't fit on one line, and since ArrayField apparently only displays one line, I couldn't view the whole array.

Finally, I discovered that the whole array would be displayed if I added the line `{{ fieldset_field.contents }}` to `django_adminreadonlyfield.html`.

However, I can't override it from myapp/templates/admin/django_adminreadonlyfield.html. How do I override it?

Answer (score 0):

It should go in app/templates/material/fields/django_adminreadonlyfield.html.